# Having to get output from using create.js in my html file?

Tags: html, createjs

*I tried to create circle using createjs for initial html game development
Here in this code the drawing API or create.js allow object draw dynamically
*

```
enter code here

<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 Course</title>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="testCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script>
        function init()
        {
            var stage = new createjs.stage("testCanvas");
            var circle = new createjs.Shape();
            circle.graphics.beginFill("Red").dreawCircle(0,0,90);**
            circle.x=250;**changing x axis**
            circle.y=250;**changing y axis**
            stage.addChild(circle); **Placing X,Y on the stage**
            stage.update();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the question ?

Comment: If nothing is drawing, it could be because `drawCircle` is spelled wrong (dreawCircle).

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you mean.  If you are trying to capture console output, here is a simple example:

```
var output = [];
var saved = console.log;
console.log = function(arg) {
  output.push(arg);
  saved(arg);
};

console.log('Hello, world!');
```

What this does is replace the inbuilt console.log method with a new one that captures console output.

Why we have a variable called saved is a backup of the old console.log before we relaced it,  so it'll still be able to write to the console.